# How to interpret this memory leak reported by Chrome Devtools with extremely deep tree of "retainers"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an AngularJS application, which is also using React underneath Angular to render some components.  The application is leaking memory, after running it in Chrome overnight, it is up to about a Gig of RAM for that tab.  I'm trying to run a memory profile, which indeed shows a lot of leaked objects.  My trouble is

1) I don't recognize what the objects are by looking at their contents
2) The Retainers view, which shows what is holding on to the objects and preventing them from Garbage collecting, is indecipherable to me and very deeply nested

The objects which are leaking all look like this:

[image: Leaked objects]

I have tried expanding the object to see if I recognize any of the contents so that I might come to some understanding of what the object is, but it seems to be a never-ending nest of something having to do with promises, as in this screenshot where I expanded the `elements` field only to find more gibberish, with another `elements` field leading to yet more gibberish:

[image: Detail of leaked object]

The Retainers tree is similarly daunting and uninformative:

[image: Retainers Tree]

when expanding the tree as deep as I can go, I eventually hit the rock bottom:

[image]

So the best I can tell, someone is calling `trim()` somewhere and that's keeping hundreds of K of memory from being garbage collected, via some very long chain of promises.

I'm fairly new to both AngularJS and React, and so I feel like there's something going on in the internals of one of those that's causing this long chain of deferred promises which is obfuscating the real problem.

The application is very large and would be difficult to post code here, so I'm just looking for more generally advice on how to approach the problem.

Comment: I think it's more like "the global object references the document that references a timer that references a callback that references `$timeout` that references a context with deferreds that reference a promise which references an array of pending callbacks that again references another promise".

Comment: Do *all* the leaked objects look like this?

Comment: @bergi, no there's a great number of objects listed in the memory profiles, those were just the most numerous and memory-consuming ones when looking at difference between two heap snapshots.  It's also a bit hard to look at the list and know which objects are leaks per se, versus objects that will be collected at some point soon, since the application is a big display with a lot of data that's constantly changing, allocating more objects and getting rid of old ones.